# ¿Como ejecutar un Script de Mysql desde java en linux?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, script, terminal

Estoy intentando ejecutar un Script .sql generado con MySQL desde una aplicación en java, he leído e investigado distintas manera de hacerlo y he encontrado varias opciones (de las cuales ninguna me había funcionado) y me encontré con el siguiente bloque de código:

```
private void executeScript (String host, String dbuser,
                                        String dbpassword, String scriptpath) {

        try {
            String[] cmd = new String[]{"mysql",
                    " --host="+host,
                    " --user=" + dbuser,
                    " --password=" + dbpassword,
                    " -e ",
                    "\"source " + scriptpath + "\""

            };
            //Aqui intente poner el commando directamente
            //String cmd = "mysql --host=192.168.0.13 --user=root_remote --password=root -e \'source "+scriptpath+"\'";
            System.err.println(cmd[0]+cmd[1]+cmd[2]+cmd[3]+cmd[4]+cmd[5]);
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            //Leemos los errores de la consola
                InputStream inputstream = proc.getErrorStream();
                InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                try {
                    if (proc.waitFor() != 0) {
                        System.err.println("exit value = " +
                                proc.exitValue());
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

El bloque de arriba me funciono correctamente en Windows, pero al momento de probar en una instalación de Ubuntu me aparece un error diciendo que la base de datos es desconocida, mas sin embargo al momento de ejecutar el comando directamente en la terminal funciona correctamente, como se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado correr el comando directamente en Runtime.exec(), como se puede apreciar en el ejemplo y sucede lo mismo, también he intentado eliminar los slash "\" antes de source y al final y tampoco funciona, repito en windows funciona correctamente, el problema es en linux, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Quizás la solución es cambiar todos los slash \ por / en vez de eliminarlos.

Comment: @ArtEze el slash "\" lo utilizo para poder pasar utilizar 'source /home/path/del/script/' ya que si no lo hago así me salta otro error, pero lo voy a intentar y te comento

Comment: @ArtEze te comento que ya intente eliminando los slash y aun el mismo error, intente tambien remplazar el comando por est "mysql --host=192.168.0.13 --user=root_remote --password=root <  /home/cbta52/Escritorio/test.sql " y lo mismo en la consola funciona bien pero desde java no

Comment: Xq no usas jdbc?? Realmente necesitas ejecutar el comando? Son simpmemente querys sql o inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comento que al fin pude resolver el problema, dejo la solución completa (Win, Linux) a continuación.

Para Linux:

```
public int runScriptLinux(String host, String dbuser, String dbpassword, String scriptpath) {

    int status = 1;

    try {

           Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{ "bash", "-c", "mysql --host="+host+" --user="+dbuser+" --password="+dbpassword+" -e \"source "+scriptpath+"\""});

          InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
          InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
          BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

          String line;
          while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
          }

          try {
               if (proc.waitFor() == 0) {
                   status = 0;
                  }
                  else {
                      status = 1;
                  }
              }
              catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     System.err.println(e);
              }

       return status;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
       return status;
    }
}
```

Para Windows:

```
public int runScriptWin(String host, String dbuser, String dbpassword, String scriptpath) {

    int status = 1;

    try {

           String pathMysql = "path de MySqlServer";

                    String[] cmd = new String[]{pathMysql+"mysql",
                            "--host="+host,
                            "--user=" + dbuser,
                            "--password=" + dbpassword,
                            "-e",
                            "\"source " + scriptpath + "\""

                    };

          InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
          InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
          BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

          String line;
          while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
          }

          try {
               if (proc.waitFor() == 0) {
                   status = 0;
                  }
                  else {
                      status = 1;
                  }
              }
              catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     System.err.println(e);
              }

       return status;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
       return status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para poder ejecutar sentencias en una base de datos desde Java se necesita usar la API JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) y en tu caso particular usar el Driver para MySql (que se puede descargar desde https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Agregado el Driver en tu proyecto, puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE", "USER", "PASSWORD");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from TABLA;";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

    //ver datos en consola
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        if (i > 1) {
          System.out.print(",  ");
        }
        String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
        System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

Esto es tan solo un ejemplo, hoy en día hay mejores opciones para conectarse a una base de datos desde Java, pero como comenté, es un ejemplo para que se note la diferencia entre el Wrapper de un comando de consola desde Java con la utilización de la API.

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar desde la terminal directamente, sugiero crear un script en Bash que realice lo que necesitas.

Saludos